# Importing a csv script via mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

Due to nda at work i can't really go into much of the other code but this is the snipit of code i'm questioning

```
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,',')) !== FALSE) {

         $csvstuff->execute($data);
         $affectedRows +=1;
        //echo "Test Rows:".$affectedRows."\n";
    }
```

My code executes properly into the db as it should. but is there anyway to protect against the csv content that comes in if it has a Erroneous

```
 ,
```

In the csv string it will break my code. Is there away to check for this and prevent that from happening?

EDIT 1: I should also note that the vendor is sending this csv over via a ftp every night so its coming from an automated system I don't control their data output of the file

Comment: read the line directly, e.g. fgets(), check if it's valid, then `str_getcsv($line)`. that's really all fgetcsv is. `function fgetcsv(...) { str_getcsv(fgets(...), ...); }`

Comment: CSV files will have text qualifier which is usually the `"` which will contain the text. Everything in between the qualifier will be treated as text even comma. `"This is, a field","This is another, field"` will be two fields. One thing that I notice can cause error is the encoding.

Comment: @frz3993 I wish this was always true. Not all CSVs will have string encapsulation.

Comment: @drmarvelous you're absolutely right. I encountered that once and the only solution I got was to ask for the people who created the csv file to use the qualifier.

Comment: If it is not encapsulated in double quotes, simply specify what it is wrapped in when you fgetcsv (fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\" ]]]] ))

Comment: It's not wrapped in anything. Only certain fields are "This is , content" those are okay, were not sure about anything else